# retrieving sub array based on sub sub value

Tags: php, arrays, sub-array

OK, so I have an array that looks like this:

```
$countries = array();
$countries['CA'] = array('name'=>'Canada','currency'=>array('code'=>'CAD','format'=>'$#')); 
$countries['US'] = array('name'=>'USA','currency'=>array('code'=>'USD','format'=>'$#'));
$countries['AR'] = array('name'=>'Argentina','currency'=>array('code'=>'ARS','format'=>'$#'));
$countries['AW'] = array('name'=>'Aruba','currency'=>array('code'=>'AWG','format'=>'ƒ#'));
```

If I have the value "ARS", how would I retrieve the entire "AW" sub array?

edit: sorry, I need the "format" next to it.

Comment: Loop through the array until you find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` to return only values from the array which match the code you're looking for:

```
$code = 'ARS';
$results = array_filter($countries, function($country) use ($code) {
    return $country['currency']['code'] == $code;
});
```

`$results` will be an array containing zero or more elements, depending on how many matches were found. For the example array in your question, this would be:

```
array(array('name'=>'Argentina','currency'=>array('code'=>'ARS','format'=>'$#')));
```

You can loop over the results, or get the first one with `$country = reset($results);` which will return `false` if no countries matched your code.

If you only expect a maximum of one match, or only want to get the first match, then you can loop over the array and `break` as soon as you find what you're looking for:

```
$found_country = null;
foreach ($countries as $country) {
    if ($country['currency']['code'] == $code) {
        $found_country = $country;
        break;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the second foreach code did the trick :) Thanks so much!